# How to install extra linux package in GCP Composer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I have written a dag which uses mongoexport command in BashOperator. By default mongoexport package is not installed in composer. I will need to install it using below command:

```
sudo apt install mongo-tools
```

We can directly install PyPi packages in composer as there is direct option available in gcp console for that.
But how can i install apt package in all nodes of composer? also that package should be effective in case of autoscaling.